# Instantiate an ArrayList by reading in lines from a Scanner, where to declare object?

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, java.util.scanner

I'd like to populate an array list with lines from an input file, the input file looks like this:

```
7f00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000027f00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000027f00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000020101
7f00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000037f00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000037f00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000030101
7f00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000047f00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000047f00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000040101
7f00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000057f00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000057f00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000050101
7f00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000067f00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000067f00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000060101
```

The data object in Java that I'd like to create based on this would have each one of those lines as a new string, and they would live together in a list, so to speak*.

So, in my attempt to read in the lines of the file into different components of this array list, I can't figure out where I need to declare the array list in my main program. My plan is to populate it in a separate method:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Array;
import java.util.ArrayList;

class evmTest {

public static void main(String[] args) {


    Array<String> inputLinesObject = new ArrayList<String>();

    // populate from file
    inputLinesObject = readFile("/Users/s.matthew.english/codes.txt", inputLinesObject);


    System.out.println(Array.toString(inputLinesObject));

}

    private static void readFile(String fileName, Array<String> inputLines) {
        try {
            File file = new File(fileName);
            Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file);
            while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
                // System.out.println(scanner.nextLine());
                inputLines.add(scanner.nextLine());
            }
            scanner.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return inputLines;
    }

}
```

Maybe I can initially instantiate it as `null`, and then pass that `null` array list to the method to be populated?

* The terms in that last sentence are not totally precise- please forgive me- I'm re-adjusting to the vocabulary of Java, nevertheless I think it should be clear enough what I'm trying to do. If not please let me know and I'll be happy to clarify.

Comment: you mean ***List<String> inputLinesObject*** dont you?

Comment: I guess? I'm really rusty in Java. What's the salient difference?

Comment: whaaat- so I can access a data structure that I declare in my `main` function from a method elsewhere in the class? and dynamically add and delete from it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this code for `readFile()` method:

```
private static List<String> readFile(String fileName, List<String> inputLines) {
    try {
        File file = new File(fileName);
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file);
        while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
            // System.out.println(scanner.nextLine());
            inputLines.add(scanner.nextLine());
        }
        scanner.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return inputLines;
}
```

and then call this `readFile()` method as below:

```
List<String> inputLinesObject = new ArrayList<String>();
inputLinesObject = readFile("/Users/s.matthew.english/codes.txt", inputLinesObject);

for(String str : inputLinesObject){
     System.out.println(str);
}
```

Comment: I kind of like this answer better than the other one- why does that one have more votes?

Comment: @s.matthew.english if you think this answer is helpful you can accept this answer.

Comment: when I wrote that I wasn't able to- since theres some minimum time limit, but- yeah- now I got you :)

Comment: It is kind of redundant to accept a list as a parameter, and then return that same list. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10403766/passing-a-parameter-versus-returning-it-from-function) and [this](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/262221/coding-style-issue-should-we-have-functions-which-take-a-parameter-modify-it).

Comment: Indeed, either you use the parameter and don't return anything, or, you don't use any parameter and return a List. And when it comes to best practices, modifying a parameter isn't in the top ones, as you could have to compare your initial data and your output data.

Answer (score 6):

For your test, you simply have to instantiate the ArrayList just above the try

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class EvmTest {

    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        // populate from file
        final List<String> inputLinesObject = EvmTest.readFile("/Users/s.matthew.english/codes.txt");

        for (final String line : inputLinesObject) {
            System.out.println(line);
        }
    }

    private static List<String> readFile(final String fileName) {
        final List<String> inputLinesObject = new ArrayList<>();

        try {
            final File file = new File(fileName);
            final Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file);
            while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
                // System.out.println(scanner.nextLine());
                inputLinesObject.add(scanner.nextLine());
            }
            scanner.close();
        } catch (final FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return inputLinesObject;
    }
}
```

That has 2 advantages:
- You don't modify an input parameter of your readFile method
- You don't have to handle the case where the List is empty or null

Comment: I got for some reason this error `error: cannot find symbol
import java.util.Array;`

Comment: I just edited the code snippet so you just have to paste it in your editor (and rename your Java file as EvmTest)

Answer (score 1):

You actually have three options:

1. Pass in a presumably empty list as a parameter into the method, and then add elements to the list:

   ```
   static void readFile(String filename, List<String> inputLines) {
       // For each line
       inputLines.add(line);
   }
   ```

   You can then call is this way:

   ```
   List<String> inputLines = new ArrayList<>();
   readFile("someFilename", inputLines);
   ```
2. Let the `readFile()` method return a list:

   ```
   static List<String> inputLines(String filename) {
       List<String> lines = new ArrayList<>();
       // For each line
       lines.add(line);

       // And then return the list with lines:
       return lines;
   }
   ```

   And then call it this way:

   ```
   List<String> lines = readFile("someFilename");
   ```
3. Don't reinvent the wheel and use functional programming to get the lines of the file:

   ```
   List<String> lines = Files.lines(Paths.get("somefile"))
       .collect(Collectors.toList());
   ```

The second one is way better than the first one, since it leaves the responsibility to create the list to the method itself. However, the latter is the best option.

---

**A few more things:**

- Stick to the Java Naming Conventions: class names should start with uppercase.
- You are using an `Array<String>`, but `java.util.Arrray` doesn't exist. I assume you mean `List<String>`.

Answer (score 0):

Create a singleton class with a composition of ArrayList.

You can create a sinleton like this

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class FileLines {

    private List<String> lines;

    private FileLines() {
        lines = new ArrayList();
    }

    private static class FileListHolder {

        private final static FileLines instance = new FileLines();
    }

    public static FileLines getInstance() {
        return FileListHolder.instance;
    }

    public void addLine(String line) {
        lines.add(line);
    }

    public String getLine(int lineNumber) {
        return lines.get(lineNumber);
    }

}
```

and in your main program use it

```
FileLines fileLines = FileLines.getInstance();
fileLines.addLine(scanner.nextLine());
```

And in other part of your programm you can retrieve a line with

```
FileLines fileLines = FileLines.getInstance();
fileLines.getLine(12);
```

Comment: Ok, I don't know what that means- but I'll look into it. Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: just to clarify- you mean that my data object should be it's own new singleton class?

Comment: i m sorry i'm french and I did not quite understand the question. my answer is complicated and off topic